# Parsing JSON within a Spark DataFrame into new columns

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

### Background

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name   |meals                                                         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Tom    |{"breakfast": "banana", "lunch": "sandwich"}                  |
|Alex   |{"breakfast": "yogurt", "lunch": "pizza", "dinner": "pasta"}  |
|Lisa   |{"lunch": "sushi", "dinner": "lasagna", "snack": "apple"}     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Obtained from the following:

```
var rawDf = Seq(("Tom",s"""{"breakfast": "banana", "lunch": "sandwich"}""" ),
  ("Alex", s"""{"breakfast": "yogurt", "lunch": "pizza", "dinner": "pasta"}"""),
  ("Lisa", s"""{"lunch": "sushi", "dinner": "lasagna", "snack": "apple"}""")).toDF("name", "meals")
```

I want to transform it into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name   |meal       |food                                              |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Tom    |breakfast  | banana                                           |
|Tom    |lunch      | sandwich                                         |
|Alex   |breakfast  | yogurt                                           |
|Alex   |lunch      | pizza                                            |
|Alex   |dinner     | pasta                                            |
|Lisa   |lunch      | sushi                                            |
|Lisa   |dinner     | lasagna                                          |
|Lisa   |snack      | apple                                            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using Spark 2.1, so I'm parsing the json using get_json_object. Currently, I'm trying to get the final dataframe using an intermediary dataframe that looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name   |breakfast |lunch    |dinner  |snack                           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Tom    |banana    |sandwich |null    |null                            |
|Alex   |yogurt    |pizza    |pasta   |null                            |
|Lisa   |null      |sushi    |lasagna |apple                           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Obtained from the following:

```
val intermediaryDF = rawDf.select(col("name"),
  get_json_object(col("meals"), "$." + Meals.breakfast).alias(Meals.breakfast),
  get_json_object(col("meals"), "$." + Meals.lunch).alias(Meals.lunch),
  get_json_object(col("meals"), "$." + Meals.dinner).alias(Meals.dinner),
  get_json_object(col("meals"), "$." + Meals.snack).alias(Meals.snack))
```

`Meals` is defined in another file that has a lot more entries than `breakfast`, `lunch`, `dinner`, and `snack`, but it looks something like this:

```
object Meals {
  val breakfast = "breakfast"
  val lunch = "lunch"
  val dinner = "dinner"
  val snack = "snack"
}
```

I then use `intermediaryDF` to compute the final DataFrame, like so:

```
val finalDF = parsedDF.where(col("breakfast").isNotNull).select(col("name"), col("breakfast")).union(
parsedDF.where(col("lunch").isNotNull).select(col("name"), col("lunch"))).union(
parsedDF.where(col("dinner").isNotNull).select(col("name"), col("dinner"))).union(
parsedDF.where(col("snack").isNotNull).select(col("name"), col("snack")))
```

### My problem

Using the intermediary DataFrame works if I only have a few types of `Meals`, but I actually have 40, and enumerating every one of them to compute `intermediaryDF` is impractical. I also don't like the idea of having to compute this DF in the first place. Is there a way to get directly from my raw dataframe to the final dataframe without the intermediary step, and also without explicitly having a case for every value in `Meals`?

Comment: If I take max(length(meals)) column to get all different meals, will this be valid assumption ?

Comment: @Manish no, sometimes the combination of meals per person is different (i.e. the longest list of meals might be missing one). You can assume that the `Meals` object has a function to return a complete list of meals, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Spark provide support to parse json data, but that should have a predefined schema in order to parse it correclty. Your json data is dynamic so you cannot rely on a schema.

One way to do don;t let apache spark parse the data , but you could parse it in a key value way, (e.g by using something like `Map[String, String]` which is pretty generic)

Here is what you can do instead:

Use the Jackson json mapper for scala

```
// mapper object created on each executor node
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

  val valueAsMap = mapper.readValue[Map[String, String]](s"""{"breakfast": "banana", "lunch": "sandwich"}""")
```

This will give you something like transforming the json string into a Map[String, String]. That can also be viewed as a List of (key, value) pair

```
List((breakfast,banana), (lunch,sandwich))
```

Now comes the Apache Spark part into the play. Define a custom user defined function to parse the string and output the List of (key, value) pairs

```
val jsonToArray = udf((json:String) => {
    mapper.readValue[Map[String, String]](json).toList
  })
```

Apply that transformation on the "meals" columns and will transform that into a column of type Array. After that `explode` on that columns and select the key entry as column `meal` and value entry as column `food`

```
val df1 = rowDf.select(col("name"), explode(jsonToArray(col("meals"))).as("meals"))

df1.select(col("name"), col("meals._1").as("meal"), col("meals._2").as("food"))
```

Showing the last dataframe it outputs:

```
|name|     meal|    food|
+----+---------+--------+
| Tom|breakfast|  banana|
| Tom|    lunch|sandwich|
|Alex|breakfast|  yogurt|
|Alex|    lunch|   pizza|
|Alex|   dinner|   pasta|
|Lisa|    lunch|   sushi|
|Lisa|   dinner| lasagna|
|Lisa|    snack|   apple|
+----+---------+--------+
```